# Is there a Linux for an MSM7227 tablet with USB keyboard and touchscreen stylus drivers?

Tags: linux, drivers, programming, tablet

I have a ZTE V9C 7" tablet with 800MHz MSM7227 processor, Snapdragon family (ARM architecture?), Android 2.3, and I want to have a (very lightweight) Linux running on it (I know Android uses a Linux kernel). I also have a physical keyboard and a stylus for it; my worries are regarding the drivers for these (the keyboard is a must because I love vim). A 3G network card OR a wifi driver is also a must for programming. And not to forget, the SD card storage support.

I want to use it for programming in/using Python, C, and Git (and an optional web browser in 'switchable' GUI) (desired: `startx` to start GUI etc). `vim` is a must for me to do development; I would like it to work well.

Also, it would be nice to be able to dual-boot with Android, in case I can't get drivers for all the hardware (e.g. the camera, phone antenna, etc.)

Is it possible to have such a Linux machine?

Comment: @Renan: Please do not remove details from the question. There was no point in you edit- removing details, capitalizing some characters and making other small case were unnecessary.

Comment: I can't find a single detail he actually removed in that edit except for the tablet model in the title, but he left it in the body; all he did was fix minor things, which is a [good thing](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#editing)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Removing '(MSM7227)' from title, 'v9c' & 'snapdragon family'from description are the details he removed if you didn't find them. I am specific about this model's drivers so I included them. Also check the last line he removed. And can you justify changing python --> Python, c --> C, git --> Git and then Vim --> vim ? Please help me understand his (and yours) motives behind this.

Comment: They're justified because those are the correct capitalizations; why are you so attached to the wrong ones? If one particular thing he changed was wrong, put it back; why do you keep rolling back all the good fixes because of one issue? I went through the whole post this time, fixed some new things he missed, and put back the things you think are important (including the part about why you want to dual-boot, not that that's at all important for answerers)

Comment: @MichaelMrozek: Capitalization corrections are not at all what I object. Removal of details is annoying. That might have guided answerers to less specific answers. Otherwise I would have appreciated the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a chrooted Linux, e.g. [Debian](http://wiki.debian.org/ChrootOnAndroid) or [openSUSE](http://michal.hrusecky.net/2012/02/opensuse-on-android/). I would expect 3G and wifi to work (since they would be handled by the Android kernel). The problem usually is the graphic card, which is (afaik) usually worked around by using VNC to connect to the chroot environment.

Comment: But running chrooted will hamper the performance as compared to directly running on top of hardware won't it?
The tab is already weak with 800Mhz processor, 512MB ROM and 512 MB RAM.